# How can I add support to scorm packages in my Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, scorm

I have a Rails 5 e-learning application that so far has supported mainly video content. In the new requirements, we've been told to add support to scorm packages as well.

I've done some Googling, however, I couldn't find much on the topic. I'm quite literally lost. I've seen that there's a [gem available](https://github.com/mindset/scorm), however, it doesn't seem to clear how to approach the problem.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: When you say "support to scorm packages" you mean to create a fully SCORM Compliant LMS, it looks like a massive project, SCORM has different angles, the first two that you will have to look are packaging (how to create the zip files with the content) and runtime (how to track usage). Maybe the information here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12016027/implemeting-scorm-player-on-my-site is useful for you, not Rails-related, but it explains a little about SCORM.

Comment: Hi Javier! Sorry, my bad, I should have been more clear. What I mean, is give the possibility to the users to follow scorm courses. This, would mean, that the admin should be able to upload the scorm zip files and the application to be able to read them and present them to the users.

I'll take a look in the meanwhile to that SO, cheers!

Comment: @ilrock have you built your own solution now?

Comment: Hey @BettySt! I did in the end. Scorm cloud was way too expensive for my clients and thus I couldn't work. It's a bit of a hack-y solution but it works.

1. When the admin uploads the file I extract everything in it and push it to S3
2. When the user needs to watch the content, I download the index.html file locally and display it in an iframe
3. I added some custom event handlers to track the progress of the user on my backend
4. I periodically delete the download files to keep the storage in check

Comment: @ilrock ha funny, i now did a similar thing: 1. upload the zip to S3, and when the user wants to view, I'll get it, unzip and temporary move it to the public folder. 2. The Rails API then returns the correct URL with the start file 3. in the frontend i show it in an iframe and save SCORM data with https://github.com/gabrieldoty/simplify-scorm back to the Rails API. .. I am also thinking about deleting the temporary files, don't know how yet, because I think on every deploy the root of the public folder changes. 

(basically what we needed was a SCORM Run-time Env, not an own Scorm API)

Comment: Hey @BettySt! and @ilrock I'm trying to do the exact same thing.  Right now I have the SCORM package hosted on S3 and it works in my iframe but the images won't load from the SCORM course.  Did you guys have that problem?  If so how did you solve it?

I didn't get to the JS part yet to handle course completion and stuff.

Comment: @ngust - It's been a while since I worked on that, however, if I recall correctly, I did face a similar problem and end up going for a not-so-great solution (still a solution). Every time a certain scorm course would be needed, I would download the scorm zip file, extract it and save the content from the /public of my rails project. Then I would load the file URL in the iframe and that solved the problems

Comment: @ilrock thanks.  I managed to get the images working that way.  I agree that is an ugly solution.  It does work though.  I'm surprised that there isn't more info on SCORM with rails.  There has to be some rails based LMS systems out there.

Comment: No probs, mate. Glad I could help. It's quite dirty indeed, but the lack of resources on scorm is staggering. I reckon it's because it is a pretty old technology and thus no need to get more stuff developed

Comment: hey @ngust , we also have our SCORM files on S3, you need to deliver the files on the same domain, so we set-up a cloudfront distribution for that. And because we are working with subdomains i got this little hack: I go through all the HTML files and add one simple script tag: `content.gsub("<HEAD>", "<head>").gsub("</HEAD>", "</head>").gsub("<head>", "<head><script>document.domain='#{domain}';</script>")`

Answer (score 0):

Implementing SCORM from scratch is an enormous endeavor. Take a look at the [ADL SCORM Reference](http://adlnet.gov/scorm) for some idea of the scope of the project. For example, see the Technical Specification zip for [SCORM 2004 4th Edition](http://adlnet.gov/research/SCORM/SCORM-2004-4th-edition/) (scroll down to find the download link)—600 PDF pages. It's not an exaggeration to say that implementing SCORM 1.2 and 2004 2nd/3rd/4th Editions will require decades of developer time, so it's probably out of the question. In fact, implementing the specs to the letter isn't enough: there's plenty of non-compliant SCORM content in the wild.

I'd recommend integrating your application with someone else's SCORM player.

If you're fine with just SCORM 1.2 and AICC support, [Moodle supports it](https://docs.moodle.org/29/en/SCORM_FAQ), and it's free.

If you need SCORM 2004 support, your best option—in my honest opinion—is to investigate the services my employer provides, [SCORM Cloud](https://scorm.com/scorm-solved/scorm-cloud-features/) (paid SaaS product) or [SCORM Engine](https://scorm.com/scorm-solved/scorm-engine/) (standalone product). These *are* commercial. As a bonus, you'll also pick up a host of other learning standards (cmi5, AICC, Tin Can) for no extra effort.

For SCORM Cloud, you can get some idea of the integration process from the documentation at [LMS Integration](https://cloud.scorm.com/docs/lms_integration.html). Instructure maintains a [community-managed SCORM Cloud Ruby client](https://github.com/instructure/scorm-cloud). If you have any questions, [ask us anything](https://scorm.com/about-us/contact-us/), even if it's not sales-related.

In all my searching, I haven't found any other feature-complete, standalone SCORM 2004 players.

(Disclosure: I work at Rustici Software, the company responsible for both SCORM Engine and SCORM Cloud.)

Comment: Thanks @Reid. I actually agree with you, Scorm Cloud would make everything so much easier. Unfortunately, this work is for a client who doesn't want to pay for the service. Thanks for the other options you've mentioned though. Will take a look at them today.

Cheers!